# Render ModelAndView as HTML in JSON with Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to return generic JSON using `@ResponseBody` in Spring, in one of the use case handling J need to return `ModelAndView` as a HTML with JSON depending on some logic.

My bean looks likes:

```
Class GenericJSON {
   String status;
   ModelAndView mav;
}
```

Now for the case when I need to return `mav` as one of the parameter in JSON, it does not goes as plain HTML rather it goes in JSON expanding the attributes of ModelAndView and whole of the model becomes a JSON and view is null.

Any suggestions how to return the JSON which contains ModelAndView and client gets it as plain HTML?

Comment: Can you copy your JSON which is going as part of your response?

Comment: please include your controller code. It's not clear to me which behaviour are you trying to achieve, can you reword your problem?

Comment: @PopFibo in my use case JSON looks like {"status":"Success","mav":{"view:null", "model":"Some relevant data"}} now the problem is when my ModelAndView does not get compiles to my expectation.

Comment: @MichałRybak the controller just contains response embedded in GenericJSON or let me say in different words , how to return HTML which is to obtain from ModelAndView and, the returning JSON also has  some more attributes in JSON to return , it's not only HTML which I need to send on client side, Hope this helps.

Comment: you need to decide is your response is `json` or `html`, there is no way to combine both. What about splitting your method into two methods, one of them returning `ModelAndView` and the other returning some JSON data?

Comment: @MichalRyback thanks for the suggestion, but losing my purpose by splitting the method.

Comment: Your purpose is unclear to me, you haven't descibed *why* you want to send response this way. Your concepts probably need redesign, if they require you to do such things. What do you want to do on client side with this data? Why do you need HTML code being sent in JSON?

Comment: @pranav you can either return html or json you cannot use them both

Comment: @MichałRybak this is kind of requirement to me also, I agree with your argument, will try to redesign the strategy of usage.